# Which all works are attributed to sage Shaunaka?

Tags: scripture, rishi

The name of Sage Shaunaka is often heard in the Puranas. The Puranas are narrated by Suta Mahamuni to the sages headed by Shaunaka.

Besides being the listener to the Puranas, he has also authored some works. I came across *Bṛhaddevatā* which contains explanation and information about the deities who were praised in the mantras of Rigveda. I also read somewhere on the internet that he has authored another book named *Ṛgveda-Prātiśākhya* which details about precise pronunciation of the mantras.

Which all works were authored (or attributed) by him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Puranic Encyclopedia](https://archive.org/details/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft/page/710) is a well known work by [Vettam Mani](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vettam_Mani&oldid=912091321). In this some famous works attributed to Shaunaka are given as below:

> [Śaunaka is believed to be the author of numerous works. The most important of them are given below:—](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc241949.html)
>
> (1) Ṛkprātiśākhya (2) Ṛgvedacchandānukramaṇī (3) Ṛgvedarṣyanukramaṇī (4) Ṛgveda Anuvākānukramaṇī (5) Ṛgvedasūktānukramaṇī (6) Ṛgvedakathānukramaṇī (7) Ṛgvedapādavidhāna (8) Bṛhaddevatā (9) Śaunakasmṛti (10) Caraṇavyūha and (11) Ṛgvidhāna. Matsya Purāṇa, Chapter 252 mentions that Śaunaka had written a work on the science of architecture.